# CSRF token changing when trying to log in with python

Tags: python, session, authentication, python-requests

I'm trying to log into a website using python **requests** with sessions. Part of the login payload is a CSRF token that can be scraped from the login page. So in order to log in, I first GET the login page to scrape the CSRF token and then POST the login credentials with the token.

The problem is that somehow the site is changing the "expected" CSRF token on me between requests. I'm not very familiar with how cookies really work, but I guess there may be something wrong with the session management.

Here's an example (anonymized a bit) where I GET the CSRF token sequentially 4 times from the same session object. Note that the token changes on the second request, but then changes back on the third and stays the same on the forth. Surprisingly the login doesn't work if I only request the page once. It does work after 3-4 requests, but as you can see that uses the same CSRF token as just requesting once! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
SESSION COOKIES: <RequestsCookieJar[]>
[GET-ing site login page]
CSRF: LK_6-aEvE_Zb_Zb_Zboo3y47yZnhEEQLS-vH0IYjAsg
RESPONSE COOKIES: <RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie incap_ses_767_1707636=sU5qZB5t8idbH0/R2u6kCnbPJFsAAAAAp8RfLoNe8mgtYX7xEvpogA== for .[domain].com/>, <Cookie nlbi_1707636_1553025=Oip3RSHTj1lZ8hPpAAAAAAAAAAC5n1FN4OAJXYHbM4x6npWy for .[domain].com/>, <Cookie visid_incap_1707636=W8ZnFEvcTM2CUn3lHxfi53bPJFsAAAAAQUIPAAAAAABeXCa4LfpmJg7LJH6MDpjE for .[domain].com/>, <Cookie AWSALB=zbarZNgpUkIrbM2FAlyUBfjV2ISjZWUxDh9gGfypqHeeB5soBr0bVGex4YKvljag1oKBwcuJRDg3u0FDXwBV3+RgLQEp8TXwf3g6ex1TNRg2y7iDvzdA+ofVhO4R for www.[domain].com/>, <Cookie SERVERID=web01 for www.[domain].com/>, <Cookie ___utmvaLzuKsciB=bgjCCaL for www.[domain].com/>, <Cookie ___utmvbLzuKsciB=kZo
    XDLOFalE: vtn for www.[domain].com/>, <Cookie ___utmvmLzuKsciB=JWWkKWKUiuL for www.[domain].com/>, <Cookie PHPSESSID=a8165be7052eef205e0a3fdf6d558ef7 for www.[domain].com/nl/>, <Cookie visitorId=5b24cf7723efe8.14153857 for www.[domain].com/nl/>]>

SESSION COOKIES: <RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie incap_ses_767_1707636=sU5qZB5t8idbH0/R2u6kCnbPJFsAAAAAp8RfLoNe8mgtYX7xEvpogA== for .[domain].com/>, <Cookie nlbi_1707636_1553025=Oip3RSHTj1lZ8hPpAAAAAAAAAAC5n1FN4OAJXYHbM4x6npWy for .[domain].com/>, <Cookie visid_incap_1707636=W8ZnFEvcTM2CUn3lHxfi53bPJFsAAAAAQUIPAAAAAABeXCa4LfpmJg7LJH6MDpjE for .[domain].com/>, <Cookie AWSALB=zbarZNgpUkIrbM2FAlyUBfjV2ISjZWUxDh9gGfypqHeeB5soBr0bVGex4YKvljag1oKBwcuJRDg3u0FDXwBV3+RgLQEp8TXwf3g6ex1TNRg2y7iDvzdA+ofVhO4R for www.[domain].com/>, <Cookie SERVERID=web01 for www.[domain].com/>, <Cookie ___utmvaLzuKsciB=bgjCCaL for www.[domain].com/>, <Cookie ___utmvbLzuKsciB=kZo
    XDLOFalE: vtn for www.[domain].com/>, <Cookie ___utmvmLzuKsciB=JWWkKWKUiuL for www.[domain].com/>, <Cookie PHPSESSID=a8165be7052eef205e0a3fdf6d558ef7 for www.[domain].com/nl/>, <Cookie visitorId=5b24cf7723efe8.14153857 for www.[domain].com/nl/>]>
[GET-ing site login page]
CSRF: jaYuITTeWLJkkMaYBsEzr7UiJKPx-Rm7JVXXR5z6Zs8
RESPONSE COOKIES: <RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie AWSALB=bGRP1ZahOQ7tILLsp8hcUXodX8cQ5LzK81r0ZcNH9/0hjjia0VERcN4sshiLsGIM5DpJ2iCaoADxjkeRInN3wCbmb7zJLV5PSF5rDrcakGEbFoA7buY23SBF+Wg6 for www.[domain].com/>, <Cookie SERVERID=web02 for www.[domain].com/>]>

SESSION COOKIES: <RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie incap_ses_767_1707636=sU5qZB5t8idbH0/R2u6kCnbPJFsAAAAAp8RfLoNe8mgtYX7xEvpogA== for .[domain].com/>, <Cookie nlbi_1707636_1553025=Oip3RSHTj1lZ8hPpAAAAAAAAAAC5n1FN4OAJXYHbM4x6npWy for .[domain].com/>, <Cookie visid_incap_1707636=W8ZnFEvcTM2CUn3lHxfi53bPJFsAAAAAQUIPAAAAAABeXCa4LfpmJg7LJH6MDpjE for .[domain].com/>, <Cookie AWSALB=bGRP1ZahOQ7tILLsp8hcUXodX8cQ5LzK81r0ZcNH9/0hjjia0VERcN4sshiLsGIM5DpJ2iCaoADxjkeRInN3wCbmb7zJLV5PSF5rDrcakGEbFoA7buY23SBF+Wg6 for www.[domain].com/>, <Cookie SERVERID=web02 for www.[domain].com/>, <Cookie ___utmvaLzuKsciB=bgjCCaL for www.[domain].com/>, <Cookie ___utmvbLzuKsciB=kZo
    XDLOFalE: vtn for www.[domain].com/>, <Cookie ___utmvmLzuKsciB=JWWkKWKUiuL for www.[domain].com/>, <Cookie PHPSESSID=a8165be7052eef205e0a3fdf6d558ef7 for www.[domain].com/nl/>, <Cookie visitorId=5b24cf7723efe8.14153857 for www.[domain].com/nl/>]>
[GET-ing site login page]
CSRF: LK_6-aEvE_Zb_Zb_Zboo3y47yZnhEEQLS-vH0IYjAsg
RESPONSE COOKIES: <RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie incap_ses_767_1707636=sU5qZB5t8idbH0/R2u6kCnbPJFsAAAAAp8RfLoNe8mgtYX7xEvpogA== for .[domain].com/>, <Cookie visid_incap_1707636=W8ZnFEvcTM2CUn3lHxfi53bPJFsAAAAAQUIPAAAAAABeXCa4LfpmJg7LJH6MDpjE for .[domain].com/>, <Cookie AWSALB=NsUMxcNSLQx+7INhsv9HoPHyhSzkMTvqUXY60JN1mm5fFByW11krdDCkYg5CPn50xrJ0cSAjqikvkw3gRvjtAfl3VwuPl7kFYleEHvbZ7jofJ6WI+pv1v7yUpGoe for www.[domain].com/>, <Cookie SERVERID=web01 for www.[domain].com/>]>

SESSION COOKIES: <RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie incap_ses_767_1707636=sU5qZB5t8idbH0/R2u6kCnbPJFsAAAAAp8RfLoNe8mgtYX7xEvpogA== for .[domain].com/>, <Cookie nlbi_1707636_1553025=Oip3RSHTj1lZ8hPpAAAAAAAAAAC5n1FN4OAJXYHbM4x6npWy for .[domain].com/>, <Cookie visid_incap_1707636=W8ZnFEvcTM2CUn3lHxfi53bPJFsAAAAAQUIPAAAAAABeXCa4LfpmJg7LJH6MDpjE for .[domain].com/>, <Cookie AWSALB=NsUMxcNSLQx+7INhsv9HoPHyhSzkMTvqUXY60JN1mm5fFByW11krdDCkYg5CPn50xrJ0cSAjqikvkw3gRvjtAfl3VwuPl7kFYleEHvbZ7jofJ6WI+pv1v7yUpGoe for www.[domain].com/>, <Cookie SERVERID=web01 for www.[domain].com/>, <Cookie ___utmvmLzuKsciB=JWWkKWKUiuL for www.[domain].com/>, <Cookie PHPSESSID=a8165be7052eef205e0a3fdf6d558ef7 for www.[domain].com/nl/>, <Cookie visitorId=5b24cf7723efe8.14153857 for www.[domain].com/nl/>]>
[GET-ing site login page]
CSRF: LK_6-aEvE_Zb_Zb_Zboo3y47yZnhEEQLS-vH0IYjAsg
RESPONSE COOKIES: <RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie incap_ses_767_1707636=sU5qZB5t8idbH0/R2u6kCnbPJFsAAAAAp8RfLoNe8mgtYX7xEvpogA== for .[domain].com/>, <Cookie visid_incap_1707636=W8ZnFEvcTM2CUn3lHxfi53bPJFsAAAAAQUIPAAAAAABeXCa4LfpmJg7LJH6MDpjE for .[domain].com/>, <Cookie AWSALB=SkTM+ORK7Q5jdS4829KCMv1Wnc3TEASkU7A8HTj/WhfpJ8t0Yd/iRJuBMK9IlG4qK+B3cycoW93ZcwpXDofgA5kaezwfWYDZftjdEbFXMN7nNhfq2aBNOssSB1r2 for www.[domain].com/>]>
```

Code to get handle the login:

```
import requests


class SiteSession(requests.Session):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        r = self.get('[site domain]/login')  # if we do this once the login fails because the csrf token is somehow wrong
        r = self.get('[site domain]/login')
        r = self.get('[site domain]/login')
        csrf_token = get_csrf_token(r.text)  # extract the csrf token from the html
        print(f'CSRF: {csrf_token}')


        payload = {'_username': [username],
                   '_password': [password],
                   '_csrf_token': csrf_token
                   }
        r = self.post('[site domain]/login_check', data=payload)


        print(f'Login status {r.status_code}')

s = SiteSession()
```

Comment: It's not going to be easy for people to help you debug your code if they can't actually see the relevant code. Please post a [mcve]. Of course, your code may be faultless, and the problem is on the server, but we need to see the code to verify that.

Comment: Sure - added my code.

Comment: Try instantiating requests.Session instead of subclassing it. It seems like that could cause problems.